# SailsJS + PassportJS (sails-generate-auth) - unable to login user

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sails.js

I am currently having a problem authenticating user in my SailsJS app using the PassportJS.

I have generated all the stuff needed for authentication using sails-generate-auth according to [this tutorial](https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/).

It seems like the POST request is routed correctly as defined in the routes.js file:

```
'post /auth/local': 'AuthController.callback',
'post /auth/local/:action': 'AuthController.callback',
```

In AuthController I've got following code:

```
callback: function (req, res) {
function tryAgain (err) {

  // Only certain error messages are returned via req.flash('error', someError)
  // because we shouldn't expose internal authorization errors to the user.
  // We do return a generic error and the original request body.
  var flashError = req.flash('error')[0];

  if (err && !flashError ) {
    req.flash('error', 'Error.Passport.Generic');
  } else if (flashError) {
    req.flash('error', flashError);
  }
  req.flash('form', req.body);

  // If an error was thrown, redirect the user to the
  // login, register or disconnect action initiator view.
  // These views should take care of rendering the error messages.
  var action = req.param('action');

  switch (action) {
    case 'register':
      res.redirect('/register');
      break;
    case 'disconnect':
      res.redirect('back');
      break;
    default:
      res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {
  if (err || !user) {
    return tryAgain(challenges);
  }

  req.login(user, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return tryAgain(err);
    }

    // Mark the session as authenticated to work with default Sails sessionAuth.js policy
    req.session.authenticated = true

    // Upon successful login, send the user to the homepage were req.user
    // will be available.
    res.redirect('/user/show/' + user.id);
  });
});
},
```

I am submitting my login form in Jade template:

```
form(role='form', action='/auth/local', method='post')
    h2.form-signin-heading Please sign in
    .form-group
        label(for='username') Username
        input.form-control(name='username', id='username', type='username', placeholder='Username', required='', autofocus='')
    .form-group
        label(for='password') Password
        input.form-control(name='password', id='password', type='password', placeholder='Password', required='')
    .form-group
        button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Sign in
    input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value='#{_csrf}')
```

I have checked the values passed to the callback function specified for password.callback(..) call:

```
passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {
```

the user variable is set to "false". I suppose, this is where the error comes from.

What is interesting is, that when the callback() function is called after user registration, the *user* variable is set right to user object containing all the values like username, email, etc.

If you would like to check other source files, my project is available on github in [this repository](https://github.com/petersiman/windsurf-sailjs).

Any help is appreciated.

Shimon

Comment: You should remove your Google OAuth credentials from the passport config file. Always place sensitive config info in `local.js`.

Comment: Thanks for tip @galactocalypse. I will fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `identifier` as the `usernameField` for `LocalStrategy` (i.e. the default setting) and have `username` in the login view, which means the authentication framework receives no username and fires a `Missing Credentials` error.

Either change the field name in the login view to `identifier` or set the appropriate `usernameField` through the passport config file (`config/passport.js`):

```
  local: {
    strategy: require('passport-local').Strategy,
    options: {
      usernameField: 'username'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about this option. I have changed the configuration in `config/passport.js` and the login works as expected. ;)